# Project Centennial Desktop - trial and time limited subscription

Tags: .net, uwp

I have an application in C# and I have idea convert my application for Windows Store by Project Centennial Desktop.
But I have two business questions:
1) is possible make trial version functionality? e.g. for 90 days
2) With the purchase of the application the customer obtains 2 years subscription and customer has possibilities install of new version.  But after 2 years the application normally works,  but new version is not possible install and use. Customer must buy upgrade.
Existing similar functionality with Project Centennial Desktop?

At the moment I am using IntelliLock for this.
http://www.eziriz.com/intellilock.htm

Thank you very much.
Regards
Nik

Answer (score 0):

Those questions aren't specific for the Desktop App Converter (ex Project Centennial), but with the Windows Store DRM.

1. you can set the free trial, but the maximum extent is 30 days.
2. there isn't a solution out of the box that would work like that.

Comment: @user3097367 no problem, just to note that according to the site rules saying 'thank you' is discouraged, while upvoting the answer is encouraged.